# How to update all the rows of a large table with different values in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to update all the rows of a large table (Postgres) in python.
For this, First I need to fetch all the rows of the table and then execute a python function updateRow(row) on all rows and then update those rows.

updateRow(row) updates values of columns according to the data present in the row hence `update myTable SET column = 'something'` won't work.

A small code snippet is as follows:

```
query = 'select * from myTable;'
cur.execute(query)
results = cur.fetchAll()


updated_results = list()
for row in results:
    updated_results.append(updateRow(row))
```

Now I want to upsert the `updated_results` in Db efficiently as the number of rows is huge (over a million). We have a composite primary key and we are not updating primary key columns in `updateRow()` function

Comment: Why not specify the update condition based on the data present in the row using a `where` clause? `update myTable SET column='something' where column2=1 and column3<5 and column4='abc';` Or even `with new_data(id,variable,value) as (values ('1',8,'Y'),('5',9,'N')) update table a set column=new_data.value from new_data where a.id=new_data.id, a.some_column > new_data.variable;`

Comment: @Zegarek, 'something' is not common for each row. Hence, each row will have different value to be updated. It will take over 1 million queries to do it. I am not able to figure out how to do this thing using `executeMany()` of psycopg2. I am more familiar in java  where we could use Hibernate to get list of Entities and uppdate those entities and insert it back to update those rows.

Comment: This is why after the first one I suggested a version of the query with a CTE that you pull your options from - you can toss in the data and the variables your update condition will depend on into the `WITH` and then refer to them in the `WHERE` clause under your `UPDATE`. In your current approach you plan to pull everything, do that 1 million edits for each row, then put it back. In what I suggest, you can properly instruct the database on the logic of your update and let it not only do the heavy lifting but also optimise it. You also save a lot of data transfer.

Comment: Why don't you implement the logic of `updateRow(row)` within the query or as a stored function? If you need help how to do it you are welcome. I think that implementing data logic out of the database where it naturally belongs and dragging large amounts of data here and back is a very bad idea no matter what language you are using. And btw ORMs are particularly poor in handling set operations.

Comment: It will help if you add example data and how your updates differ between rows. As to the `upsert` part, it's done using `insert into table t (id,col1,col2) values (id,col1,col2) on conflict (id) update (col1,col2)=(excluded.col1,excluded.col2)`. And if you want to compare different methods of inserts from psycopg2, here's a [good comparison with examples and benchmarks](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql).

Comment: Thanks @Zegarek for the pointers, I will try them out and update here.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm It is just a one-time task we need to do as a part of migrations.

Comment: Why python and psycopg then? Just write your (maybe not trivial) update query in a SQL console and run it.